# WP7 XNA displaying 3D FBX model

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, fbx

I am just begginer so sorry for my silly question.

my model looks like this: http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/8291/clipboard01ap.jpg

but in result in XNA looks like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHxHKZnjgnM

I hope you can see the weird transparency...

Is the problem connected with "EnableDefaultLighting()" ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Z-Buffering ( Sorting ) is not enabled or is not initialized in the right way.
Found this on the internet:

Most likely reasons:

- Is the DepthBufferEnable renderstate set?
- Does your projection matrix have sensible near and far clip plane values?